# Best way to use a custom table in a relationship (in ExpressionEngine)?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, expressionengine

So, I’m a bit on how to use a separate table in a relationship, or something like that…

I have a table with around 5000 hotels called `exp_h_hotels`.
On my website, I use the `pages` module to create a static subpage for each part of the country.   I want to list all hotels that belong to a specific region.

I have understood that I can’t do something like this (using ExpressionEngine tags with the query module):

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_h_hotels WHERE h_regionname ='{regionname}'"}
       {hotel_name}
{/exp:query}
```

Anyone knows the best way to go forward with this?

I have looked into using the ExpressionEngine API to insert the data into a channel – however, I get the feeling that it wouldn’t be optimal to flood the channel entries table with 5000 posts with 14-20 fields with data each.

Comment: Never use `select *` list the fields you want explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps you want a join? `select h.hotelname, h.address FROM hotels h INNER JOIN regions r ON (h.region_id = r.id) WHERE r.regionname = 'champagne'`

Comment: Perhaps – but how do I get the ExpressionEngine-tag ({regionname}) to funtion inside the exp:query-tag?

Comment: I'm not hep on [codeigniter], I was just asking you to clearify the question, do you need a join or not? Because your title says: "Best way to use a custom table in a relationship" and now you're asking "ExpressionEngine-tag ({regionname}) to funtion inside the exp:query-tag". I recommend you rewrite the question (and esp the title) to be much more specific and focussed on your technical point.

Comment: Okay, thought that the question was clear when I tagged the question ExpressionEngine and Codeigniter. But as you wish, I will rewrite the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why this *shouldn't* work as you expect, so long as your `exp:query` tag is inside your `channel:entries` tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" limit="1"}
<h1>Hotels in {regionname}</h1>
<ul>    
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_h_hotels WHERE h_regionname ='{regionname}'"}
   <li>{hotel_name}</li>
{/exp:query}
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, for the long-term, importing your hotels into a new channel in EE is a much better plan. You could export from your database to CSV (using phpMyAdmin perhaps) and then import into EE using [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab). Nothing wrong with adding 5000 new entries to EE.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip regarding the plugin, might be worth buying actually... So adding so many posts to EE will not affect the performance in a big way?

Comment: EE can handle that data, just be sure to set cache and refresh parameters in the exp:channel:entries tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I will probably go that way instead – that way I can use the built in search-tag in EE instead of wring lots of SQL. Thanks again.